# Cannot create unique key from execute immediate in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a trigger that fires off everytime a new row is inserted in my table audit_ddl.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_after_insert_audit_ddl AFTER
    INSERT ON audit_ddl
    FOR EACH ROW
    declare
        ddl_qry     VARCHAR2(4000);

BEGIN
 ddl_qry := 'ALTER TABLE reese33 ADD CONSTRAINT reese33_uk2 unique(tut_name) enable';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ddl_qry;

END;
```

I am just playing around with it and want to add a unique key to a table. However, I get an error saying

```
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'DS.AUDIT_DDL_TRG'
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-30511: invalid DDL operation in system triggers
ORA-06512: at "SD.TRG_AFTER_INSERT_AUDIT_DDL", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SD.TRG_AFTER_INSERT_AUDIT_DDL'
ORA-06512: at line 16
```

Just to be clear: there are no constraints in the table yet. I realize that the same constraint cannot be created twice. This is just for testing.

Also, I am able to create primary constraint, foreign constraints on the table using execute immediate but unique key provides an error.

This query

```
ALTER TABLE reese33 ADD CONSTRAINT reese33_uk2 unique(tut_name) enable
```

works fine when I run it independently in a script.

I think I have all the privileges:

[image]

I also tried to run queries to create views and procedures and turns out I face the same error.

Comment: please show the exact error message.

Comment: I don't think you can execute ddl in a trigger.  put it in a stored proc and call that from the trigger.

Comment: I tried that and it gives me the same error.

Comment: If this is just for testing, use `pragma autonomous_transaction` and see the result.

Comment: You say "This query `ALTER TABLE reese33 ADD CONSTRAINT reese33_uk2 unique(tut_name) enable` works fine when I run it independently in a script". In that case the constraint already exists, and running the same command again should produce the error `ORA-02261: such unique or primary key already exists in the table`. [db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7735e50461695e1fafcece8bf9025b95)

Comment: oh yes.. i did that for testing if the query was correct... and i removed the constraint again to test it from the trigger.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is a bit unclear as to what the problem is:

```
ORA-30511: invalid DDL operation in system triggers
```

This mistakenly indicates that this is a system trigger - it is not. System triggers *can* contain certain DDL statements (CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE, DROP TABLE and ALTER...COMPILE), but non-system triggers such as this are not allowed to execute DDL. [Manual reference here - search for "SQL Statements Allowed in Trigger Bodies"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#LNPLS020) where you will find that "A nonsystem trigger body cannot contain DDL or transaction control statements.".

When you create a constraint it stays in the database until it is removed. I suggest you create your constraint in an SQL window or similar.